# Issues with including header files

Tags: ios, xcode, nsoperation

In my application I have several classes, that cross-over with each other. I need to connect this classes and create properties of them, but some classes are not visible for another, I suppose that main issue here is in including header files.

class MyOperationQueue

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ContentTableView.h"
//#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"
//#import "ObjectForTableCell.h"

@interface MyOperationQueue : NSOperation

@property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL isCancelled;
@property(strong, nonatomic) ContentTableView* tableView; //unknown type name
```

class ObjectForTableCell

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyOperationQueue.h"

@interface ObjectForTableCell : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) MyOperationQueue* currentQueue;//unknown type name
```

class ContentTableView - here I don't have warnings

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"
#import "Protocol.h"
#import "MyOperationQueue.h"
#import "ObjectForTableCell.h"
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@interface ContentTableView : UITableViewController<CellDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick a `@class MyOperationQueue;` above

```
@interface ObjectForTableCell : NSObject
```

to make it:

```
@class MyOperationQueue;

@interface ObjectForTableCell : NSObject
```

Here is an excerpt from official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOPandObjC1/OOPandObjC1.pdf):

> **Referring to Other Classes**
>
> An interface file declares a class and, by importing its superclass,
>   implicitly contains declarations for all inherited classes, from
>   NSObject on down through its superclass. If the interface mentions
>   classes not in this hierarchy, it must import them explicitly or
>   declare them with the @class directive:
>
> ```
> @class Rectangle, Circle;
> ```
>
> This directive simply informs the
>   compiler that “Rectangle” and “Circle” are class names. It doesn’t
>   import their interface files. An interface file mentions class names
>   when it statically types instance variables, return values, and
>   arguments. For example, this declaration mentions the NSColor class.
>
> Since declarations like this simply use the class name as a type and
>   don’t depend on any details of the class interface (its methods and
>   instance variables), the @class directive gives the compiler
>   sufficient forewarning of what to expect. However, where the interface
>   to a class is actually used (instances created, messages sent), the
>   class interface must be imported. Typically, an interface file uses
>   @class to declare classes, and the corresponding implementation file
>   imports their interfaces (since it will need to create instances of
>   those classes or send them messages).
>
> The @class directive minimizes the amount of code seen by the compiler
>   and linker, and is therefore the simplest way to give a forward
>   declaration of a class name. Being simple, it avoids potential
>   problems that may come with importing files that import still other
>   files. For example, if one class declares a statically typed instance
>   variable of another class, and their two interface files import each
>   other, neither class may compile correctly.

There is also an excellent article (by NSHipster) on various other compiler directives [here](http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/). I recommend reading it, for this knowledge will likely serve you well in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes things get messed up when you create circular imports, i.e. *MyOperationQueue.h* and *ContentTableView.h* import each other.

A common fix is to remove at least one of those imports and replace them with forward declaration of the classes, i.e. add `@class ContentTableView;` to *MyOperationQueue.h*.

You should then import ContentTableView.h in your implementation file *MyOperationQueue.m*, so that the whole interface is known. This typically also helps reduce compile time.